# wrap paragraph lines into span-tags (with jQuery) and use conditional classes

Tags: jquery, text, numbers, conditional-statements

I am trying to wrap each line of a paragraph into a span tag. That works so far (thanks to the code I found). Now I am trying to bring in conditions. What I want is to check if the string (o a certain line) contains a certain text or pattern and if so, I would like to manipulate the output.

```
var txt = $(".ym-col1 p.address").html().split("<br>")
var output = ""
for(var x=0;x<txt.length;x++) {
    if($("txt[x]:contains(\"08\")")) {
        output = output + "<span class=\'telephone\'>"+txt[x]+"</span><br>"
    }
        if($("txt[x]:contains(\"@\")")) {
        output = output + "<span class=\'email\'>"+txt[x]+"</span><br>"
    }

}
$(".ym-col1 p.address").html(output);
```

If I only use the output with the if() it works but with the if I get each line of my text double. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

And another question. :)
Is there a smart way to check if a string contains more than 5 digits? (Example: 123456)

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net...  use of jQuery on the items in array is incorrect

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing jQuery in the `if` statements, you should use `indexOf` method of the String object:

```
$(".ym-col1 p.address").html(function(i, html){ 
     var txt = html.split('<br>'), output;
     for(var x = 0; x < txt.length; x++) {
         if ( txt[x].indexOf("08") > -1 ) 
             output += "<span class='telephone'>"+txt[x]+"</span><br>"
         else 
             output += "<span class='email'>"+txt[x]+"</span><br>"
     }
     return output;
})
```

Comment: That makes totally sense and works.
Thanks undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a jQuery object (aka a wrapped set):

```
$("txt[x]:contains(\"08\")")
```

It will always create a wrapped set, even if the wrapped set is empty, so the following conditional is always true:

```
if($("txt[x]:contains(\"08\")")) {
```

If you want to check if a wrapped set is not empty, you can use:

```
if($("txt[x]:contains(\"08\")").length > 0) {
```

But if what is between the `<br>` tags is just text, you shouldn't even be using a wrapped set. You could use something line this:

```
if (txt[x].indexOf("08") >= 0) {
```

and

```
if (txt[x].indexOf("@") >= 0) {
```

Comment: Hey John, 
these are very helpful information. I will try that tomorrow. 
Thank you! :)